# Kindly help to get office wise data row wise

Tags: oracle, monthcalendar

```
select NUM_OFC_CODE,NUM_RO_CODE, 
 case when TXT_MONTH='JAN' then 1 ELSE 0 end as JAN,
case when TXT_MONTH='FEB' then 1 ELSE 0  end as FEB,
case when TXT_MONTH='MAR' then 1  ELSE 0 end as MAR,
case when TXT_MONTH='APR' then 1 ELSE 0  end as APR,
case when TXT_MONTH='MAY' then 1 ELSE 0  end as MAY,
case when TXT_MONTH='JUN' then 1 ELSE 0 end as JUN,
case when TXT_MONTH='JUL' then 1 ELSE 0 end as JUL,
case when TXT_MONTH='AUG' then 1 ELSE 0 end as AUG,
case when TXT_MONTH='SEP' then 1 ELSE 0  end as SEP,
case when TXT_MONTH='OCT' then 1 ELSE 0  end as OCT,
case when TXT_MONTH='NOV' then 1 ELSE 0  end as NOV,
case when TXT_MONTH='DEC' then 1 ELSE 0 end as DEC 
 from LEG_OMBUDSMAN_NONMACT where
 NUM_YEAR=2019   group by NUM_OFC_CODE,TXT_MONTH,NUM_RO_CODE;
```

Result is showing as below:-

```
NUM_OFC_CODE    NUM_RO_CODE JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC

280400          280000      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1           0   0
282300          280000      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0       0   0
281600          280000      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0       0   0
280500          280000      0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0       0   0
280500          280000      0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0       0   0
281800          280000      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0       0   0
282200          280000      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0       0   0
280500          280000      0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0       0   0
280500          280000      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0       0   0
280500          280000      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0       0   0
281300          280000      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0       0   0
```

I want office wise data. If August data is present, Then It should show 1 else 0.  Like wise for other months. But in my query Separate row is showing for separate months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to group the data only by `NUM_OFC_CODE,NUM_RO_CODE` (excluding TXT_MONTH as you don't want a row for each instance of TXT_MONTH) and then use something like `NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN TXT_MONTH='JAN' THEN 1 END), 0) as JAN` (using a aggregate function to decide wether an entry exists or not) etc.

It's easier with the use of pivot:

```
-- Just some sampledata:
WITH LEG_OMBUDSMAN_NONMACT(NUM_OFC_CODE, NUM_RO_CODE, NUM_YEAR, TXT_MONTH) AS
  (SELECT 1,1,2019, 'JAN' FROM dual union ALL
  SELECT 1,1,2019, 'FEB' FROM dual)
-- Here starts the actual query:
SELECT NUM_OFC_CODE, NUM_RO_CODE
     , NVL(JAN,0) AS JAN
     , NVL(FEB,0) AS FEB
     , NVL(MAR,0) AS MAR
     , NVL(APR,0) AS APR
     , NVL(MAY,0) AS MAY
     , NVL(JUN,0) AS JUN
     , NVL(JUL,0) AS JUL
     , NVL(AUG,0) AS AUG
     , NVL(SEP,0) AS SEP
     , NVL(OCT,0) AS OCT
     , NVL(NOV,0) AS NOV
     , NVL(DEC,0) AS DEC
  FROM LEG_OMBUDSMAN_NONMACT
  pivot (MAX(1) FOR TXT_MONTH IN ('JAN' AS JAN,'FEB' AS FEB,'MAR' as MAR, 'APR' as APR, 'MAY' as MAY, 'JUN' as JUN, 'JUL' as JUL, 'AUG' as AUG, 'SEP' as SEP, 'OCT' as OCT, 'NOV' as NOV, 'DEC' as DEC ))
 WHERE NUM_YEAR=2019
```

Comment: Following error is showing by executing the query:-  "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

Comment: I have use single quote, double quotes as below 'JUL' as "JUL". But none of its working.

Comment: With which oracle version are you working? Perhaps `pivot`-queries are not supported in your version.

Comment: Yes. After googling, I came to know 10g Does not support Pivot. by the way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is perfectly fine, just need couple of changes.

1. Remove txt_month from group by.
2. Use Max in all case statements.

So your query should look like this

```
select NUM_OFC_CODE,
    NUM_RO_CODE, 
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='JAN' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as JAN,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='FEB' then 1 ELSE 0  end) as FEB,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='MAR' then 1  ELSE 0 end) as MAR,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='APR' then 1 ELSE 0  end) as APR,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='MAY' then 1 ELSE 0  end) as MAY,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='JUN' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as JUN,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='JUL' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as JUL,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='AUG' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as AUG,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='SEP' then 1 ELSE 0  end) as SEP,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='OCT' then 1 ELSE 0  end) as OCT,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='NOV' then 1 ELSE 0  end) as NOV,
    Max(case when TXT_MONTH='DEC' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as DEC 
     from LEG_OMBUDSMAN_NONMACT 
    where NUM_YEAR=2019   
    group by NUM_OFC_CODE ,NUM_RO_CODE;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Why have you copied my solution? It's exactly what i have stated in upper part of my answer...